# Tracking a bowling ball down the lane

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision

So I'm working in this app and got many things done, i can track the ball perfectly on my current videos ( just a small part of the lane currently ). The Idea is to be able to track a bowling ball down the whole lane to calculate all sorts of things ( like speed and position ). My problem is that lanes are 60 foot ( 18m ) long and like 4 ( 1.1m ) wide. I figured the best way to do it was putting the Cameras on the ceiling, because background extraction worked flawlessly so my first test was a USB webcams. My first problems were to discover that ceilings are almost 10 foot ( 3m ) from the floor so i would need a lot of webcams, when i got 1 more i realized 2 things, webcams are not the way because:

a) It doesn't support the bandwidth of streaming the video of many cameras at the time at high res.

b) I would need a lot of webcams because of fixed lens sizes.

c) Unless you use powered cables USB doesn't get very far before losing singal

So i discovered what it seemed to be the solution that is something like 1 or 2 PointGrey cameras (Butterfly or other model) with maybe a 4mm or 8 mm lens would work. At this point my financing is very low and I'm trying to have the least amount of possible errors as is my own startup and as an Argentinean is not as easy to do stuff like being in the US.

My question is what kind of approach would you guys take to be able to capture the whole lane? maybe change camera positions and use other way instead of background extraction? You guys think I'm going on the right track? with the USB cam, at least i was able to capture and follow frame by frame the ball in a very limited space of lane, but i realized i can do everything i want and the project is possible, but USB is not the way.

Hoping to hear some advice as I'm no expert in computer vision or cameras. and i want to do a cost efficient project. I'm currently working on C# using emgu.

Thanks to anyone took the time to read this :)

[image: Here is an image of my current progress]

Answer (score 0):

These approaches came to my mind:

1- I seems that with one camera on the ceiling your system works well but you do not cover the whole lane. Then you can calculate the speed and position in the portion you cover and make an estimation for when the ball goes of the field of view.

2- Another approach is to use a camera with a wider angle on the ceiling.

3- Instead of on the ceiling, you can mount the camera somewhere else (for example on the sides) that covers the whole lane. Since you exactly know the location of your camera you can calculate speed and position based on the location of the ball on the screen (taking into account prespective,etc). The problem with this approach would be that you have to mount the camera always in one point for all customers and the system won't work if camera moved later.

4- The most robust approach to me is stereo vision. You use two cameras with a certain distance to each other, calibrate them. Then you can mount them anywhere that covers the whole lane. Distance, speed, position, etc are all feasible and easy to extract when you have the matrices of two cameras.

Answer (score 0):

put a camera at an angle where it can see the whole lane. For example, you can mount it on a ceiling looking down and forward. Background subtraction should just work fine while the distance can be calibrated based on the initial and final position of the ball. The mapping between the image and the physical world (lane surface) will be given by Homography which requires 4 point correspondences to calculate.